# Free real-time file replication tool?

Tags: file-management

Does anyone know a free, real-time file replication tool similar to [RepliWeb R1](http://www.repliweb.com/products/r1/index.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest **rsync** and some scripting as a solution.
But, then there could be some downsides and effort as I read at this post about RepliWeb from a user: [How one tool solved all 5 risks](http://contentdeployment.wordpress.com/2008/02/06/how-one-tool-solved-all-5-risks/).

So, if you want freeware and you are ready for some 'risks' (correctly comparing them to how critical your deployment is), **rsync** might still be a good base tool.

As an example,
[Warsync](http://freshmeat.net/projects/warsync/) (Wrapper Around Rsync) is a perl based server replication system mainly used to sync servers in LVS clusters. It is based on rsync over ssh and has native support for Debian package synchronization.

Comment: +1 For the excellent replication blog/article.  I'm still digging into rsync to see if that will work, but like you said, it comes with some risks.  If no-one posts a better alternative by the end of the week, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Should link to http://contentdeployment.wordpress.com/2008/02/06/how-one-tool-solved-all-5-risks/